# How to read an MS Access database from Jupyter using pyodbc

Tags: python, database, ms-access, jupyter, pyodbc

I have a problem reading my access database from Jupyter using the pyodbc module. This is my code:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\javansf\Documents\Database4.accdb')
```

I cannot progress beyond this point and keep getting the below error:

```
InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-e7f04283f996> in <module>()
----> 1 conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\javansf\Documents\Database4.accdb')

InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I am using Python 3.9 (64-bit), and MS Access 365 (64-bit, Access 2007-2016 file format, office 16). My jupyter uses Python3 as its kernel.

I'll appreciate your help in addressing my problem.

Comment: Which exactly driver did you install ? x86 or x64 ? As you are using 64Bit Python 3.9 then you must use x64 bit driver.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean the driver in access?

Comment: Apart from Python 3.9 (64-bit), Python 3.6 (32-bit) is also installed on my machine. Wondering it might cause this problem.

Comment: I am not sure about the driver. May you let me know how I can check which driver is installed?

Comment: Check the same code on Python 3.6 32bit

Comment: Take a look at odbc admin

Comment: Open PowerShell and run this command: [Get-OdbcDriver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/wdac/get-odbcdriver?view=win10-ps). Or specifically with args: `Get-OdbcDriver -Name "Microsoft*" -Platform "64-bit"`

Comment: The interesting point is that I can execute 'import pyodbc' inside Jupyter with no problem, whereas when I run the same code in the Python shell it says 'No module named 'pyodbc'. Not sure why it happens!!!!

Comment: Sounds like Jupyter is running on a different Python install, perhaps even a different machine. Since this is an installation issue, provide as many details as you can on the installation.